# MDX Member on Cube issue

Tags: ssas, mdx

I m try to run the below query but in get error

> Parser: The statement dialect could not be resolved due to ambiguity.

```
 WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Test] AS
    SUM({[Item Dimension].[DivCode]},{[Item Dimension].[ItemCode].Allmembers},[Measures].[Stock Qty],[Measures].[Sales Qty])

    SELECT 
        {[Item Dimension].[DivCode]},{[Item Dimension].[ItemCode].Allmembers} ON ROWS
        ,[Measures].[Stock Qty],[Measures].[Sales Qty] ON COLUMNS
 FROM dbCube
```

Any help?

Answer (score 1):

You have missed a few brackets and have placed a few incorrectly 
Try below

```
 WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Test] AS
    SUM(
    ([Item Dimension].[DivCode],[Item Dimension].[ItemCode].Allmembers),
    [Measures].[Stock Qty],[Measures].[Sales Qty])

    SELECT 
    ([Item Dimension].[DivCode],[Item Dimension].[ItemCode].Allmembers) ON ROWS,
    {[Measures].[Stock Qty],[Measures].[Sales Qty]} ON COLUMNS
    FROM dbCube
```

Comment: in line `([Item Dimension].[DivCode],{[Item Dimension].[ItemCode].Allmembers),` there is an `{` which does not close. y?

Comment: It was a typo,Fixed it. Does it solve your problem.

Comment: i m receiving the following error: `Query (4, 33) Too many arguments were passed to the SUM MDX function. No more than 2 arguments are allowed.`

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I got the answer.

```
WITH MEMBER [Measures].[Test] AS
SUM(
        {(
            [Item Dimension].[DivCode]
            ,[Item Dimension].[ItemCode].Allmembers
        )}
        ,[Measures].[Stock Qty]
    )
SELECT 
([Item Dimension].[DivCode],[Item Dimension].[ItemCode].Allmembers) ON ROWS,
{[Measures].[Stock Qty],[Measures].[Sales Qty]} ON COLUMNS
FROM dbCube
```